# Solving Spring-mass system in Python using odeint

Tags: python

I am solving a second-order ODE for a harmonic oscillator numerically with Python using odeint. From the code below my plot, it appears that the system is not damping at all as expected. Can someone please help me with debugging my code? Below is the code I have written so far.

[Mass Displacement and velocity plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BBtD.jpg)

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
    
    ########################### Given Parameters ######################
    l = 125e-6 #m
    w = 20e-6 #m
    h = 5e-6 #m
    rho = 2300 #Kg/m3
    Q = 300
    A_0 = 20e-9 #nm
    gamma_sv = 30e-3 #J/m2
    H = 6e-20 #jouls
    R = 20e-9 #m
    E_t = 130e9 # Pa
    v_t = 0.3
    E_s = 70e9 #Pa
    v_s = 0.3
    
    ################## Calculated Parameters from Homework7 #############################
    I = (w*h**3)/12
    mu = rho*w*h
    C_1 = 1.8751
    K_c = (3*E_t*I)/(l**3)
    w_0 = (C_1**2/l**2)*np.sqrt(E_t*I/mu)
    w_d = w_0
    f_0 = w_0/(2*np.pi)
    m = K_c/w_0**2
    gamma = m*w_0/Q
    F_0 = (w_0**2*m*A_0)/Q
    
    # F_D = (F_0 * np.cos(t))/(A_0*m*w_0**2) 
    
    E_star = (E_s*E_t)/(((1-v_t**2)*E_s)+((1-v_s**2)*E_t)) # Estar
    a_0 = np.sqrt((H)/(24*np.pi*gamma_sv)) #molecular distance meters
    
    #NonDimensionalized Constants
    lambda = 1/(A_0*K_c)
    beta = 1
    alpha = 1/Q
    
    #Initialization
    tstart    = 0
    tstop     = 20
    increment = 0.01
    
    #intital Conditions
    x_init = np.array([0,1])
    
    t = np.arange(tstart, tstop+1, increment)
    
    #Function returning the dxdt
    
    def mydiff(x,t):
        #gamma = m*w_0/Q                                 #Damping Constant
        K_c = (3*E_t*I)/(l**3)                           #Stiffness of the mass
        m = K_c/w_0**2                                   #Mass
        F_D = (F_0 * np.cos(t))/(A_0*m*w_0**2)           #Driving force
            
        dx1dt = x[1]
        dx2dt = F_D - alpha*x[1] - beta*x[0]      #NonDimensional Equation being solved
                
        dxdt  = [dx1dt, dx2dt]
        return dxdt
    
    # Solving the ODE
    x = odeint(mydiff, x_init, t)
    
    x1 = x[:,0]
    x2 = x[:,1]
    
    #Plotting the Results
    # plt.plot(t,y)
    
    plt.plot(t,x1)
    plt.plot(t,x2)
    #plt.title("Damped and Driven Harmonic Oscillator with F_ts = 0")
    plt.xlabel("t/s")
    plt.ylabel("x(t)")
    plt.legend(["Displacement (x1)", "Velocity (x2)"], loc="upper right")
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include more details, such as the ODE you're trying to solve. Most of the people here are programmers and may not have a background or recent experience in Physics / Engineering to know the equations of motion of a spring-mass-damper system

Comment: *"...  it appears that the system is not damping at all as expected."*  It *is* being damped, but your system also includes a sinusoidal forcing term (computed as `F_D` in `mydiff`), so you are seeing the response to that forcing.  Remove `F_D` (and increase `t_stop` a bit) and you'll see the decay.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thanks my professor said the same thing.